# how to find out rows based on a column where duplicate data exist

Tags: sql-server-2008

Suppose, I have a table like this-

```
Code  | something
------------------
C01     abc
C02     mnt
C03     lkj
C01     dhl
C04     poi
C05     gtr
C02     rty
C01     asd
-------------------
```

Now, I want only those rows from the table, which rows have `Code` more than once in that column. So, output will be like-

```
Code  | something
------------------
C01     abc
C01     dhl
C01     asd
C02     mnt
C02     rty
-------------------
```

I'm new with sql server and query things. Please, help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE code IN (
    SELECT Code FROM Table
    GROUP BY Code HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: dont worry you will be improving by time

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from YourTable
where Code in
(
    select Code
    from YourTable
    group by Code
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH codes AS 
(
  SELECT code 
  FROM dbo.table
  GROUP BY code 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT code, something 
  FROM dbo.table AS t
  INNER JOIN codes AS c 
  ON t.code = c.code;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.* 
FROM TableName, (SELECT Code from TableName T1 
                 GROUP BY T1.Code 
                 HAVING (COUNT(T1.Code) > 1)) T3
WHERE T2.Code = T3.Code
```